# Trouble finding out if this counts as a read/many reads/will I get charged loads on database costs?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently developing an iOS app with a google cloud firestore as a backend and I am using a few listeners to find out if data is updated and then pushing it to my device accordingly. I wrote this function that listens for a value if true or not and according to so will update an animation in my app. The trouble is I don't know if I wrote it properly and don't want to incur unnecessary reads from my database if I don't have to.

```swift
func dingAnimation() {
        let identifier = tempDic![kBOUNDIDENTIFIER] as! String
        if identifier != "" {
            dingListener = reference(.attention).document(identifier).addSnapshotListener({ (snapshot, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: error!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
                let data = snapshot.data() as! NSDictionary
                for dat in data {
                    let currentId = FUser.currentId() as! String
                    let string = dat.key as! String
                    if string == currentId {
                    } else {
                        let value = dat.value as! Bool
                        self.shouldAnimate = value
                        self.animateImage()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's nothing in that code to listens for a value that's *true or not*. Also, it looks like the listener is on a single document? Or is there child data involved? We don't know what your Firestore looks like and without that, the question is vague.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

**From Firestore DOCS - Understand Cloud Firestore billing**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing

> **Listening to query results**
>
> Cloud Firestore allows you to listen to the results of a query and get realtime updates when the query results change.
>
> When you listen to the results of a query, you are **charged for a read each time a document in the result set is added or updated. You are also charged for a read when a document is removed from the result set because the document has changed.** (In contrast, when a document is deleted, you are not charged for a read.)
>
> Also, if the listener is **disconnected for more than 30 minutes** (for example, if the user goes offline), you will be **charged** for reads as if you had issued a **brand-new query.**